# Add adobe illustrator file into HTML

Tags: html, css, vector-graphics, adobe-illustrator

I have been given an .ai (adobe illustrator artwork 19.0) file to add to my HTML page. After a bit of testing it seems that I can't add this using a normal `<image>` tag.

What's the best practice for this?

Comment: I understand we're talking about a little asset to insert (a logo, a graph, a map...), not a complete page design to implement, is that right?

Comment: That is correct. Why has this question been downvoted...?

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Inkscape but an illustrator output is also a vector file. There should be a .svg output, try exporting to that output type and you can use that with the  tag.

There's a variety of ways to use svg on HTML
Here's what I commonly use:

1. `<img>` way:  `<img src="url.svg">`
2. Inline SVG way:  Open up the file in your favorite editor (Sublime or notepad), copy the code and past it on the html code.

Edit

To do it your way:

- Convert your .ai file to a .svg file. I successfully did by using an online tool. (You could even use the output svg itself and use it on the `<img>` tag)
- Open it up in notepad
- Copy the code to the HTML file
- Optional: optimize SVG code to make it shorter(There's a bunch of online tools for that)

Warning: Using inline SVG, particularly extremely large ones could take a toll on your site's responsiveness. But less intricate and small ones should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @kdyz unfortunately I am not allowed to change the file :(

Comment: @BarneyChambers Edited it.

Comment: @BarneyChambers Them you are probably done with it. Adobe Illustrator is a very specialised format. You can't even open it in a regular desktop computer unless you install a viewer, nonetheless in a browser. It's as if you'd been ask to embed smells inside HTML :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, as much as I know, there isn't any practice of this. The closest thing I can think of is:

http://ai2html.org  (you have to use image_format:svg)

You can also export it to a different file type if this is a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

"Adobe Illustrator Artwork (AI) is a proprietary file format developed by Adobe Systems for representing single-page vector-based drawings in either the EPS or PDF formats. The .ai filename extension is used by Adobe Illustrator." - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Illustrator_Artwork

You can open it with Adobe illustrator or photoshop, and export it out as an image file.

If I were you if all you wanted was an image, then just export it out as either a png or jpg and use that new file on your page.

You can also export it out as a vector and use the vector image on the site, if you are unsure how then the comments here seem to have helped explain how, but here's a link that I found useful:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Adding_vector_graphics_to_the_Web